# How to reuse a subroute across multiple routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am thinking about transferring an application using Vercel to Next.js. This application has a partial routing structure as follows (simplified):

```
/
└── entries/
    └── <entryId>/
        ├── ...graphRouter
        └── context/
            ├── iterator/
            │   └── ...graphRouter
            └── <variableId>/
                └── ...graphRouter
```

The shorthand is a router used for navigation around a graph view, which has it's own nested routes. Currently I use react-router where I can define partial router schemas and then use these multiple times in the final router schema. How would I go about this using Next.js file system routing? Is it possible to have subroute definitions and then reuse these across your application?

The current solution I have in mind is creating the full file system graph routes everywhere, but have the implementation of the routes come from a shared components folder. This is still not great however, as it would mean having lot's of duplicated nested files which are essentially empty.

Comment: Basically having the same situation. Replicating those routes manually is kind of a show stopper for us to go with next.js

Answer (score 1):

Use a router library such as [`react-router`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main).

It provides a more flexible way to define and manage routes, but it require more setup than using Next.js file system routing.

If you are already using `react-router`, you can continue to use it with Next.js. To do this, you need to install the [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom).

Once you have configure Next.js to use react-router, you can define your subroutes in the same way that you would in any other React app. You can now reuse your subroutes in other routes by using the `<Route>` component.

Comment: With using a different router than the built-in one of next.js, you would lose certain benefits of using a framework like next.js, e.g. using server rendered components. So this would not be a real solution for me, when it comes to the question of using next.js in favor of a "plain" react app.

Comment: You can use dynamic route to define the subroute once and then reuse it in other routes. It will less repetitive, but it can be more difficult to understand and maintain by your teammate.

Comment: Could you provide an example for the "dynamic subroute"?